# What does it mean to have a branch point at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis

Particularly, I am looking at the problem $w=(z^3-1)^\frac{1}{3}$. It seems obvious that there is a branch point at 1. I know that for non-integer $p$, the function $z^p$ has a branch point of infinity. I'm wondering if this means that $w$ will have a branch point of infinity as well?

I suppose, I'm not entirely sure what it means to have infinity as a branch point -- and any clarification of this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It means $f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ has a branch point at $0$

Comment: Most definitions involving infinity in complex analysis are defined through what happens to $f(1/z)$ for $z$ near zero.

Comment: The Riemann sphere motivates the point at infinity from a geometric perspective. It's relatively easy to understand in that context.

Comment: There are also branch points at $\frac12(1\pm i\sqrt3)$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng can you clarify how you find these as branch points? I see why they are, but would not have been able to identify them.

Comment: @Mike you find them by setting $z^3-1$ equal to $0$ and solving for $z$.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f(z)=(z^3-1)^{1/3}$,
$$f(1/z)=\left(\frac{1}{z^3}-1\right)^{1/3}=\frac{(1-z^3)^{1/3}}{z}.$$
Near zero, each branch of $zf(1/z)$ is holomorphic (indeed on $\{z:|z|<1\}$)
and so each branch of $f(1/z)$ is meromorphic (with a simple zero at $\infty$).
So at $\infty$, each of the three branches of $f(z)$ is meromorphic, so $\infty$
is **not** a branch point of $f$, but each branch does has a simple pole at $\infty$.